# iOS clang: error Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I try to integrate Unity project to iOS Project.
I configure xcode project, use key "-weak-ISystem', but appear error

[image: configure key "weak-ISystem" in Other link flag]

When i build project, appear error:

[image: Appear error]

How to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `-weak-lSystem` not `-weak-ISystem` (i.e. `l` and not `I`).